# DraftJS: How to store editor's content in Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, draftjs

I am creating an empty editor state in my Redux reducer with this:

```
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js'

const defaultState = {
  editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
}

const editor = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_EDITOR_STATE':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        editorState: action.payload.editorState
      })

    default: 
      return state
  }
}
```

But the editorState that is injected in the props is a plain Object:

```
EditorState { _immutable: {} }
```

So I am having errors like getCurrentInlineStyle is not a function

When I create the editorState from the constructor instead, everything is fine, I have a Record Object:

```
EditorState { _immutable: Record }
```

Am I doing something wrong with my Redux reducer ?

Thanks.

Comment: the editorState injected into the props is going to be dependent on the value passed in as `action.payload.editorState`. How are you dispatching your action?

Comment: no, the initial value is the defaultState, EditorState.createEmpty(). The same function (createEmpty()) seems to return different value when called from the component constructor or a reducer

Comment: I am certainly not describing my issue well enough. Thanks any way.

Comment: I finally think that when the editorState object is stored, it is converted from an ImmutableJS record to a plain JS object. So it loose all Record attributes. I better save convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()). I can later reconstruct the state using convertFromRaw.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem here.